# How to install udisks1 in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, udisks

I have several scripts that I need for various tasks with USB devices, but they were written with udisks1 in mind. Porting them over to udisks2 has proven difficult, if not impossible, so I'm wondering how I can go about installing udisks1 on a CentOS 7 system.

I know the two programs can coexist without issue, I just have no idea where to find a CentOS 7 package for udisks1. Google was no help, so I'm turning to here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the package you need for CentOS 7 is oldudisks and you should add [nux-desktop](http://li.nux.ro/repos.html) repo to install it.
To install the program run:

```
yum install oldudisks
```

Comment: Thanks! That link you gave didn't work right for me, but googling for "oldudisks centos 7" lead me to [this](http://pkgs.org/centos-7/nux-dextop-x86_64/oldudisks-1.0.4-14.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html) which lead me to the right package.